# How to print formulae and literals when using CVC5?

Tags: smt, z3py, cvc4

I am playing with the CVC5 example at https://github.com/cvc5/cvc5/blob/main/examples/api/python/pythonic/linear_arith.py.

```
from cvc5.pythonic import *

slv = SolverFor('QF_LIRA')

x = Int('x')
y = Real('y')

slv += And(x >= 3 * y, x <= y, -2 < x)
slv.push()
print(slv.check(y-x <= 2/3))
slv.pop()
slv.push()
slv += y-x == 2/3
print(slv.check())
slv.pop()
```

It works as it is supposed to work.

However, whenever I try to print the content of the formula (i.e., `print(slv)`), it raises the following error: `Cannot print: Kind.CONST_INTEGER`

The same happens with literals that compound the formula: i.e., `print(x >= 3)`; but not with variables: `print(x)` returns `x`.

I would like to have this printing capability, since Z3 allows it and I am trying my (originally-in-Z3-made) implementation with different SMT sovlers. Any idea?

Note that `print(slv)` does return info (`[]`), when it is empty. I tried using `str()`, but the error persists and indeed I guess `print()` uses `str()` before printing.

PS: I am using CVC5, should I use CVC4 or is CVC5 mature enough?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is a bug. You should report it to the CVC5 folks at https://github.com/cvc5/cvc5/issues. (i.e., they should be able to handle this case just fine.)

In the interim, you can use the following workaround:

```py
print(slv.sexpr())
```

which prints:

```
(and (let ((_let_1 (to_real x))) (and (>= _let_1 (* 3.0 y)) (<= _let_1 y) (> x (- 2)))))
```

which takes a bit of squinting to see that this is what you asserted, but it should do the trick.

Comment: Yep, the only thing that 'dirties' the result are those 'let's, but it will make it :)) I will ask the question.